# add what was printed to a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

list2 = ['A'. 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I print out every time I called my function a random element of each list:

```
def whatever():
    print 'Element of list 1: ', random.choice(list1), 'Element of list 2: ', random.choice(list2)
```

I need to add these printed elements to a dictionary (this I'm not sure if it's the best solution) in order to keep track of how many times each of these elements have been printed and I need save this dictionary into a persistent file.

This is what I need:

```
new_list1 = {}  # initially empty
new_list2 = {}  # initially empty
```

After the first called to my function:

```
new_list = {'element4 of list1':1, 'element6 of list2': 1}
```

and every time I called the function, my new_list will be updated and saved with the updates.
After called the function several times:

```
new_list = {'element1 of list1':1, 'element1 of list2': 1,
            'element2 of list1':1, 'element2 of list2': 2,
            'element3 of list1':2, 'element3 of list2': 1}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save them to variables first before printing them so you still have them once you're out of the `print` statement. Then do as you will. By the way, is `new_list` a list or a dictionary? You're writing it as a dictionary but you're talking about it as a list, so I don't know what you're trying to do. Sample inputs and outputs would be sweet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class which does this for you:

```
 from collections import defaultdict

 class AutoTrackingDict(dict):
   def __init__(self, **kwargs):
     super(AutoTrackingDict, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     self.counter = defaultdict(int)

   def __str__(self):
     for key in self.keys():
       self.counter[key] += 1
     return str(self.counter)
```

By overloading the `__str__` you get a print out of all the keys plus the number of times they've been accessed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a newbie in Python and I don't know yet how to use classes. Could you explain me how to implement this in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by making a dictionary where the keys are values in the respective list.. and start at 0

```
count_dict1 = {}
for element in list1:
    count_dict1[element] = 0
count_dict2 = {}
for element in list2:
    count_dict2[element] = 0
```

or with comprehension

```
count_dict1 = {element:0 for element in list1}
count_dict2 = {element:0 for element in list2}
```

Then before you print each line, store the value in a temporary variable, such that you can find it in the `count_dictx` and increment the value.

```
def whatever():
    element1 = random.choice(list1)
    element2 = random.choice(list2)
    count_dict1[element1] += 1
    count_dict2[element2] += 1
    print 'Element of list 1: ', element1 , 'Element of list 2: ', element2
```

Comment: thanks for your advice, but every time I call my function, my new_list is reinitialized, and I need to save it (read my message with the updates)